# Regex.Replace using variable instead of static value

Tags: c#, regex, data-binding

I trying to format a data bound label value as a phone number, with brackets around the first 3 numbers.

If I manually enter a value for Regex to format, it shows correctly. If I use a variable, and I will have to as the number will change with each record that is viewed, the value doesn't get formatted.

For example:

```
string pattern = @"(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})";
string replace = "($1) $2 $3";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace("11122223333", replace);
lblTelephone.Text = result;
```

will show (111) 2222 3333 in lblTelephone, but if I replace the input string with a variable value, formatting does not happen.

```
//Strip any spaces from the number, orignal number is 11122 223333 in the database
string phone = lblTelephone.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
string result = rgx.Replace(phone, replace);
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to parse the `lblTelephone`? Maybe there's an input field called something else...

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine so your problem is elsewhere
(I mean it's not in the fact that you're using a variable).
Probably the value of `phone` is not what you think it is.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string phone = "11122223333";
        string pattern = @"(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})";
        string replace = "($1) $2 $3";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = rgx.Replace(phone, replace);
        Console.WriteLine(result); 
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Are you saying you're using (111) 2222 3333 as input the second time?
If so, your problem is the presence of the brackets around 111. 
Remove them too just as you removed the spaces.

**EDIT 2:**

It is quite possible that in the DB you see the value 11122 223333 but actually you have some invisible char (as suffix or prefix) or something similar. Check the string length in the DB and the exact string value.

Comment: I'm sorry, the string length once the spaces were removed was only 10, and the regex was expecting 11. Shall check more thoroughly next time. Thank you both.